# Psql Command Line Password and Query

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line-interface, psql

I am trying to make a one line psql request. I would like to send both  credentials and query in the same time.
I am using this :

```
psql.exe "dbname=dbname user=postgres password=postgres host=localhost" -c 'select * from table'
```

Actually if i take back the -c option it works but right now it sends me this :

```
psql: attention : option supplémentaire « 'select » ignorée
psql: attention : option supplémentaire « * » ignorée
psql: attention : option supplémentaire « from » ignorée
psql: attention : option supplémentaire « view' » ignorée
```

The connection to the database worked but thoose logs are in french but they mean "care : option skipped".

I tried with Url request

```
psql.exe postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/dbname -c 'select * from view'
```

But this is the same.

Do you have any idea where i am misplaying this ?

Thanks !

Comment: I am using the latest version of PostgreSQL : 13 !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys, found the solution. After a better read of the --help, i figured that

```
psql [OPTIONS]... [NOM_BASE [NOM_UTILISATEUR]]
```

Connexion options are to be used after the query so instead of psql [CONNEXION] -c "blabla"
Use this

```
psql -c "select * from table" "dbname=dbname user=user password=password host=host"
```

or

```
psql -c "select * from table" postgresql://user:password@host/dbname
```

Take care about your double quotes too.

Bye,

Answer (score 2):

```
psql postgresql://myusername:myPassword@127.0.0.1:5432/myDB
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes, not single quotes, to protect a string with spaces in Windows' `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Agreed.
Fact is, with the double quote, it just gonna skip the whole in once!